# Apache HttpComponents Async Client Setting Request Body Issue

Tags: java, http, networking, multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm learning examples of latest [apache hc async client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/examples-async.html). The **response streaming feature** is very useful and exactly what I need(such as calculating latency when each chunk arrived, which seems lack in `CloseableHttpClient`).

But having trouble **setting the request body**.

Take the [AsyncClientHttpExchangeStreaming](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/AsyncClientHttpExchangeStreaming.java) as example, I can run this example, but when trying to add some body to request, like following, I find it not work(*httpbin* response is very clear, and `data` or `json` field is empty).

```java
      String bodyString = "{\"k\":\"v\"}";
      final SimpleHttpRequest request = SimpleRequestBuilder
        .post()
        .setHttpHost(target)
        .setPath("/post")
        .setBody(bodyString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .build();
```

Then I noticed `client.execute(new BasicRequestProducer(request, null),` and tried to replace `null` with
`new BasicAsyncEntityProducer(bodyString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);`, this time *httpbin* tells me it received the bodyString(is this walkaround correct and why need?).

When I tried posting multi part form, like above walkaround, the server reports errors such as 'content-length missing' or 'malformed request':

```java
    final StringBody inputBody = new StringBody(inputJson, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    final StringBody parametersBody = new StringBody(parametersJson, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    final HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addPart("Input", inputBody)
        .addPart("Parameters", parametersBody)
        .build();
    //above reqEntity can successful request my server in sync client
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reqEntity.writeTo(baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    BasicAsyncEntityProducer multiPartProducer = new BasicAsyncEntityProducer(
        bytes,
        ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
    );
```

I searched a lot and [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511766/constructing-a-multipart-request-from-inputstream-with-apache-async-http-client) says the `HttpEntity` created by `MultipartEntityBuilder` cannot be used along with async client. I'm very disappointed and frustrated. Could anyone suggest the correct way in apache hc, or rather other libraries instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution and answer myself, hope helpful for some newcomers like me.
Still welcome more elgant solution.

- Cause of the issue

  `HttpEntity` created by `MultipartEntityBuilder` is wrapped into `BasicAsyncEntityProducer` as bytes, library sends the bytes as they are, and http post header missing boundary information.
- Solution

  Get the `Content-Type` header including the boundery info then update it into request headers.

```java
//get the `Content-Type` header including the boundery info
//value is like:
//Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=ISO-8859-1; boundary=fLC0K1nKdSI-Q9vzFpU2WleMTXyWbOBp6
String contentType = reqEntity.getContentType();
final SimpleHttpRequest request = SimpleRequestBuilder
//...omit other methods
.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType)
```